# using mixed absolute units on SVG elements where SVG size is also in absolute units

Tags: svg

Here is an example document, sized to US Letter paper size (8.5 x 11in). There is a `<rect>` that should be 1in wide and 1cm tall.

```html
<svg width="8.5in" height="11in" viewBox="0 0 8.5 11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="1px" y="1px" width="1in" height="1cm" fill='black'/>
</svg>
```

But it doesn't display correctly. It seems like inside of `<svg>`, it is treating the `viewBox` units as pixels rather than inches, creating a 8.5x11px viewport rather than 8.5x11in. When displayed on screen, the 96px/in density makes the rectangle 96px wide, filling the entire viewport.

How do I make this document display correctly at varying DPIs? Both on screen at 96px/in and on paper at 300px/in? Note that I ***do not*** want to convert the units manually (e.g. from 1cm to 0.393700787in or vice versa).

Comment: 8.5 in the viewBox means that something that's 8.5 (units) wide will take the whole width i.e. 8.5 inches. (units) would be px because unspecified units in SVG are px although 1px in SVG is unlikely to be 1px on the screen given viewBoxes and transforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set a `viewBox` attribute.

You want the real-world units provided for grafical elements to be true when the element is rendered. In other words, you do **not** want a transformation to be applied. But the `viewBox` attribute is a [special way](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#Introduction) to write a transformation:

> Each SVG viewport generates a viewport coordinate system and a user coordinate system, initially identical. Providing a ‘viewBox’ on a viewport's element transforms the user coordinate system relative to the viewport coordinate system.

Implicitely, without the attribute the viewport coordinate system and the user coordinate system remain identical.

Comment: Interesting. I had wanted to use `viewBox` for other reasons, but I believe I can work around that with `transform`s

Comment: You can also nest `<svg>` elements. Place the elements with absolute units in the outer one, and add `width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="..."` to the inner one.